# Traversing all files in windows pc and create report due to creation date in an efficient way in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, filesystems, traversal

My client wanted me to write a simple desktop app such that :

User will select a date. Then the program will travel all files in the windows pc and then create an excel report for all files which are created before the selected date.

Actually it seems really simple application. However, my client told me he has petabytes of data which made me think the app would run for hours even days. I need a really smart solution for that. For instance despite the possibility of a crash or unexpected error etc, I am planning to divide the report into parts and create a new excel file for each 50000 records. In addition, the application should continue from where it left off. In another words, if the application is closed, the application should not start scanning all over again. What is the most logical way for the program to work efficiently and continue from where it left off? What comes to my mind is to put a tick on the folders so that the already looked folders are not looked at again. What is the best way to implement this logic in C#? Is it efficient to create a separate list for the visited folders and then first look if the folder is alreay in list? Which data structures would you use for this problem and how would you implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: See, normally I'd think of using something like DirectoryInfo's EnumerateFileSystemInfos, but since you want to resume it, you would probably need to do the iteration manually and save where you are with some way of resuming from there.

Comment: And What If some file appears in a directory you already hace scanned with a creation date that is earlier than what the client would have selected (eg: the user selected a date in the future / extracted a file that was in an archive) ?

Depending on the answer to these questions, you might not be able to resume.

Comment: From the moment the program is decided to run, no changes will be made to the file system

Comment: C# list won't work above int32.maxvalue (~2 billion), so if you have mostly smaller files this is going to be a problem.